# Decoding Byte Array to String and Replace String contents and encode it back?

Tags: java, arrays, string, byte

i have a byte Array, i want to replace the word "404" with "replaced".
I tried this code:

```
    byte[] fileData = Utils.readFileData(file, filelength);



    CharsetDecoder decoder = StandardCharsets.US_ASCII.newDecoder();

    decoder.onMalformedInput(CodingErrorAction.REPLACE);
    decoder.onUnmappableCharacter(CodingErrorAction.REPLACE);
    decoder.replaceWith("?");

    String string = decoder.decode(ByteBuffer.wrap(fileData)).toString();

    string = string.replace("404", "replaced");

    fileData = string.getBytes();
```

but it throws and error at decorder.decode():

```
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.nio.ByteBuffer.wrap(Unknown Source)
    at de.cfp.webserver.ReturnAnswer.ok(ReturnAnswer.java:70)
    at de.cfp.webserver.WebServer.run(WebServer.java:93)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

So, huh? How to do this now?

Answer (score 0):

The most likely cause of the NullPointerExceptoin is fileData being null.

Can you check if Utils.readFileData(file, filelength); returns null?
You could add a check after Utils.readFileData. This helps debugging.

```
byte[] fileData = Utils.readFileData(file, filelength);
if (fileData == null) throw new RuntimeException("The file is " + file.getName() + " could not be read");
```

If this is the case, I'd update Utils so it'll handle missing files incorrectly.